# Javascript - ReferenceError x is not defined (function)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Trying to do Chrome extension development. Problem is I don't know how to use JavaScript.

Currently I think the issue is that I don't know how to call or define functions.

Calling page_PostData() results in an undefined exception:

VM150:13 Exception ocurred:
ReferenceError: page_postData is not defined

This code is slightly modified from the sample extension Chrome Query:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/devtools/panels/chrome-query.zip

devtools.js

```
function page_postData(variableData) {

    console.log("Trying to do AJAX POST...");
};


function page_getData() {

    try {

        console.log("Trying to get data..");

        // Not defined.
        page_postData("Test1");

    } catch (exception) {

        console.log("Exception ocurred:\n" + exception.toString());
    }

    return $0;
};


chrome.devtools.panels.elements.createSidebarPane(
    "Element Properties",
    function(sidebar) {
  function updateElementProperties() {
    sidebar.setExpression("(" + page_getData + ")()");
  }
  updateElementProperties();
  chrome.devtools.panels.elements.onSelectionChanged.addListener(
      updateElementProperties);
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Chrome Extension Test",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "Dev tools test extension",
    "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["devtools.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", 
        "http://*/*", 
        "https://*/*"
    ]
}
```

devtools.html

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="devtools.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I define 'page_postData()' correctly?

How do I call 'page_postData()' from inside 'page_getData()' correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context issue, since the expression will be evaluated in context of the inspected page, there would be no definition for `page_postData`.

You can create an [IIEF](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to wrap the two functions, sample code would looks like:

```
function run() {
    function page_postData(variableData) {
        console.log("Trying to do AJAX POST...");
    }

    return (function page_getData() {
        try {
            console.log("Trying to get data..");
            page_postData("Test1");
        } catch (exception) {
            console.log("Exception ocurred:\n" + exception.toString());
        }
        return $0;
    })();
}

chrome.devtools.panels.elements.createSidebarPane(
    "Element Properties",
    function(sidebar) {
        function updateElementProperties() {
            sidebar.setExpression('(' + run + ")()");
        }
        updateElementProperties();
        chrome.devtools.panels.elements.onSelectionChanged.addListener(updateElementProperties);
    }
);
```

Comment: This sample code works, except $0 is not getting returned the same way it was before (sidebar is now empty instead of being populated with the currently selected elements properties). Any solution for that?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

To run `page_postData()` from `page_getData()` you need to pass correct context. You should learn more about `bind` and `apply` functions. In your example you sould call `page_getData()` in the way like this: `page_getData.bind(this)()`.

Comment: Thank you for the help as well, I will look into these more.